# Wireless not working after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Dell Vostro, wireless is not working. The "Enable Wireless" option is also missing.

I tried the command **lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net** and got the following output:

```
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02bc]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

0e:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: The following solution worked: Installation of Firmwire installer for the b43 driver through ubuntu software center followed by a reboot.